# How can I reduce this kind of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery('.msnf-form-step').each(function() {
  if (jQuery('li:nth-child(2)').hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery('.active').prevAll().addClass('finished');
  }
  if (jQuery('li:nth-child(3)').hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery('.active').prevAll().addClass('finished');
  }
  if (jQuery('li:nth-child(4)').hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery('.active').prevAll().addClass('finished');
  }
  if (jQuery('li:nth-child(5)').hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery('.active').prevAll().addClass('finished');
  }
  if (jQuery('li:last-child').hasClass('active')) {
    jQuery('.active').prevAll().addClass('finished');
  }
});
```

Comment: Since all the branches do exactly the same thing, why do you have the `if`s at all? Why do this repeatedly in `each`? What does the HTML look like? What is the goal?

Answer (score 0):

you can just select an .active element

```
jQuery('li.active')
```

So you only need

```
jQuery('li.active').prevAll().addClass('finished');
```

Could you explain why do you need each() loop?

```
jQuery('.msnf-form-step').each(function() {
    //
});
```

Comment: sorry. I am just a beginner. I didn't know. Thank you so much.